# Integrating velocity equation?

Tags: calculus

I don't understand what I am doing wrong. I have the first part of the question right which is the velocity equation. Then to find total distance traveled, you take the antiderivative of the velocity equation from part a and substitute in 3 seconds. However this is wrong. Isn't this how you're supposed to do it? The problem is in the picture.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxRtW.png)

Answer (score 0):

The *area* under the curve of a velocity-time graph will be the total distance traveled, while the definite integral will be the displacement. Plugging in $3$ to the indefinite integral of the velocity function will not work because you have an unknown constant. Instead calculate $$\int_0^3 |v(t)|dt$$
or if you're not allowed to use a calculator, find if out if $v(t)$ is always positive on $[0,3]$. If not, split the integral. If so, evaluate normally.

Comment: So if I split into[ 0,1] and [1,3] I get -65/3 and 380/3. And like Jerry suggested I add the two separate integrals. I get 105, which is the wrong answer like before?

Comment: @EdwardStark On $[0,1]$, $|v(t)|=-10t^2-30t+40$ so the distance travelled is +65/3.

Answer (score 0):

You've confused distance with displacement.  The particle has negative velocity until t=1, then it turns around and moves in the positive direction.  So you need to do two separate integrals, from 0 to 1 and from 1 to 3 and add the magnitudes of the two integrals of v.